# Using multiplication instead of logical AND

Tags: performance, logic

Is there any reason why using multiplication instead of logical AND operator would be preferred or discouraged (using any programming language)? Example below shows that it could make the code simpler, but are there any other advantages (or disadvantages)?

```c
int x = 1;
int y = 0;
int z = 1;

int xyz_mult = x*y*z;
int xyz_and = ((x && y) && z);
```

Take the simple example in R:

```r
library(rbenchmark)
library(Rcpp)

benchmark(T*F*T, (T&&F)&&T, replications = 1e6)
##           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
## 2 (T && F) && T      1000000   2.974    1.000     2.965    0.004          0         0
## 1     T * F * T      1000000   3.201    1.076     3.187    0.008          0         0
```

and's are slightly faster. But with using Rcpp it is multiplication that gets faster with `int` variables while (counter-intuitively) being faster with `bool` variables:

```r
xyz_and_int <- cppFunction("
int foo() {
   int x = 1;
   int y = 0;
   int z = 1;
   return (x && y) && z;
}
")

xyz_mult_int <- cppFunction("
int foo() {
   int x = 1;
   int y = 0;
   int z = 1;
   return z*y*z;
}
")

xyz_and_bool <- cppFunction("
int foo() {
   bool x = 1;
   bool y = 0;
   bool z = 1;
   return (x && y) && z;
}
")

xyz_mult_bool <- cppFunction("
int foo() {
   bool x = 1;
   bool y = 0;
   bool z = 1;
   return z*y*z;
}
")
```

And here are the simulation results:

```r
benchmark(xyz_and_int(), xyz_mult_int(), replications = 1e6)
            test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
## 1  xyz_and_int()      1000000    3.32    1.000      3.33        0         NA        NA
## 2 xyz_mult_int()      1000000    3.34    1.006      3.33        0         NA        NA
benchmark(xyz_and_bool(), xyz_mult_bool(), replications = 1e6)
             test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
## 1  xyz_and_bool()      1000000    3.36    1.015      3.34        0         NA        NA
## 2 xyz_mult_bool()      1000000    3.31    1.000      3.31        0         NA        NA
```

Comment: Do you mean `int xyz_and = ((x & y) & z);`? And yes, bit operations are usually way faster than multiplications.

Comment: @PhilippGrassl treat this example as pseudocode.

Comment: Okay I think you should call it the "boolean and" in your question so it's clear you don't mean the bitwise and.

Comment: @PhilippGrassl ok, changed to "logical and" to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken, multiply is done either with shift registers or adders of some sort. Their implementation is always more complicated than just an AND gate, therefore they're "less efficient".

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense, but still it is multiplication of 0's and 1's. So I wonder if it makes that much difference in practice.

Comment: I think it is, since the logic implementation doesn't change whether you multiply 0's and 1's or any other number. As long as more complex logic elements involved the efficiency goes down.

Comment: Unfortunately not... see my edit - in some cases multiplication seems to *be* faster than and's. So it seems to be more complicated and here my question starts.

Comment: Can't we conclude, according to performance times, that rcpp adds much more overhead? It's around 65% slower than rbenchmark, while the difference between and's and multiply is between 2-5% (according to tests). So I think better measurement is needed, maybe a much bigger number of operations to test, preferably without calling a function.

Comment: For sure it adds overhead but it adds the same overhead to both xyz_and() and xyz_and() so it should be comparable. I do not argue it is a "proof" but rather an example that shows it actually can behave counter-intuitively, i.e. with multiplication being a little bit faster (for sure not slower).

Comment: Yeah but it's like those functions (in math) when one is "bigger" than the other because for N that is big enough the bigger function is always, well... bigger, than the other one, even if for "smaller" N's that might not be the case.

Comment: OK, but for smaller number of replications measuring performance of such simple operations would result in a bunch of 0's for their timings...

Comment: Actually I say the opposite :-) More replications!!! (I don't take responsibility for your CPU's suffer ;-))

Comment: With 1e7 replications multiplication is still slightly faster (xyz_and has relative timing of 1.008). The example shows is could be at least not slower.

Comment: Wait, now I saw the difference between 2 measurements, in first case you worked with booleans where in second one with ints, worth trying with booleans in rcpp too. Plus, as I've said before, try not to wrap it in function (avoid new stack, return addresses, etc'),

Comment: See my edit, the more I digg it gets even funnier ;)